# How to marshal C# List with X++ List in MS Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: c#, interop, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have an MS Dynamics AX 2012 project and I am using .Net interop.
There is a C# method inside a `static class` called `Database`:

```
 public static List<String> GetAllDatabases(string dataSource)
```

After referencing this assembly, I can execute in X++:

```
ADOMD.ADOMD.Model.Database::GetAllDatabases();
```

But I can't read the string list that it's returning.
I would like to use something like:

```
List databaNameCollection = new List( Types::String ); 
;

databaNameCollection =  ADOMD.ADOMD.Model.Database::GetAllDatabases();
```

But it trows an error:

```
Error executing code:  (object) has no valid runable code in method 'GetSID'.
```

How could I do it?

**-------EDITED------**

I found this post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/x/archive/2010/01/19/traversing-elements-in-an-ienumerable-from-x.aspx

But it was in 2010, probably for AX 2009, I tried to assign:

```
ClrObject enumerator; 
str theValue;
;

enumerator = ADOMD.ADOMD.Model.Database::GetAllDatabases();
while (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
    { 
        theValue = enumerator.get_Current(); 
        print theValue; 
    }
```

The GetallDatabases method is working with another .Net project, it is returning 10 objects, but at the X++ code, is returning nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about .NET types in X++ and `get_{x}` and `set_{x}`:

.NET properties are shown in X++ as methods. For example, the get & set property below in C#

```
string Name {get;set;}
```

will show in X++ as

```
string get_Name();
void set_Name(str value);
```

Basically C# properties are just syntactic sugar. The C# compiler will create a get_{x} method for each get property and a set_{x} for each set property.

In your case, if you want to access the `Name` property in the cubeDef object you would have to write something like this in X++:

```
info(cubeDef.get_Name());
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it using the example at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/x/archive/2010/01/19/traversing-elements-in-an-ienumerable-from-x.aspx

But without the `enumerator.MoveNext()`, since it is not an X++ Object, changing it to a `for` loop worked, the final code is:

```
ClrObject enumerator;  
str theValue;
int i;
int length = 0; 
List databaNameCollection = new List( Types::String );
;  

try
  { 
    permission = new InteropPermission(InteropKind::CLRInterop);
    if (permission == null)
    {
            return;
    }
    permission.assert();
    enumerator = ADOMD.ADOMD.Model.Database::GetAllDatabases();
    length = enumerator.get_Count();

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        stringElement = enumerator.get_Item(i);
        databaNameCollection.addStart(stringElement);
    }
     CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
 }
 catch (Exception::CLRError)
 {
     CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
     info(CLRInterop::getLastException().ToString());
 }
```

But some **questions** still remain:

1) I can't assign `databaNameCollection.addStart(enumerator.get_Item(i));` directly.

2) I can't access the complex objects attributes, like:

```
cubeDef  = enumerator.get_Item(i);
info(cubeDef.Name);
```

where `cubeDef` is of type: `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CubeDef`.

3) I can't find the documentation of the [CLRObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/clrobject.aspx) that describes these `get_{propertyName}` methods.
EX: `get_Item`

Best Regards